# Android: how to make the items from listview opens to diff. activity/intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-listview, barcode

I created a listview and would like to know how to have each diff. item open diff. activity/intent
example: In listview
-start trip (it will grab the gps location data send that to the server right away and confirm its been sent)

-Clock in (it will grab the time/date data and send that to the server right away and confirm its been sent)

-Customer Svc (intent to the barcode scanner and return result no display and send result data to the server

right away)
-Independent Inspection (intent to the barcode scanner and return result no display and send result data to the

server right away)
-Pick Up (intent to the barcode scanner and return result no display and send result data to the server right

away)

-Log out (it will ask for password to complete a log out)

Im using project 2.2 with sdk 3 will be using the 1.5 firmware device motorola i1. I imported the zxing barcode

scanner "android integrate" to the project which should open the barcode scanner app seperately. .I am using eclipse. One last thing I am getting error at resultTxt and would like to know how to fix that problem?

Thanks
Merrill

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/selection" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Customer.java**

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Customer extends ListActivity
{
    TextView selection;
    String[] items = { "Start Trip", "Clock in", "Customer Svc", 
            "Independent Inspection", "Pick Up", "Log Out" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
        selection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selection);
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.company.merrill.IntentIntegrator");
        intent.setPackage("com.company.merrill");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
    {
        if (requestCode == 0)
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                // contents contains whatever the code was
                String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");

                // Format contains the type of code i.e. UPC, EAN, QRCode etc...
                String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");

                // Handle successful scan. In this example 
                // I just put the results into the TextView
                resultsTxt.setText(format + "\n" + contents);
            }
            else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
            {
                // Handle cancel. If the user presses 'back' 
                // before a code is scanned.
                resultsTxt.setText("Canceled");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is resultsTxt? where is it declared? initialized?

Comment: it was taken from the code sample assuming it might be part of the class imported.

Comment: If it's not declared anywhere, there must be a compilation error on the lines you use it. Based on it's name and the usage of `setText`, it might be a `TextView` instance, but it has to be declared and initialized somewhere (either globally, or inside the `onActivityResult` method), like `final TextView resultsTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.results_txt);`

Comment: okay i could play around with that. Do you happen to know the solution/sample for my main question? What i know is how to open another page (activity) at the click of the button but as for this listview there are diff. ways and not even sure how to put it together within same page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start different activities based on the position in the `ListView` of the item you just clicked:

```
private static final int ACTIVITY_0 = 0;
private static final int ACTIVITY_1 = 1;
private static final int ACTIVITY_2 = 2;

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    final Intent intent = new Intent();
    // Set up different intents based on the item clicked: 
    switch (position)
    {
        case ACTIVITY_0:
            intent.setClass(this, com.company.merrill.IntentIntegrator.class);
            break;
        case ACTIVITY_1:
            intent.setClass(this, com.company.merrill.SecondActivity.class);
            break;
        case ACTIVITY_2:
            intent.setClass(this, com.company.merrill.ThirdActivity.class);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    // Pass the item position as the requestCode parameter, so on the `Activity`'s
    // return you can examine it, and determine which activity were you in prior. 
    startActivityForResult(intent, position);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        // Perform different actions based on from which activity is
        // the application returning:
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case ACTIVITY_0:
                // contents contains whatever the code was
                String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");

                // Format contains the type of code i.e. UPC, EAN, QRCode etc...
                String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");

                // Handle successful scan. In this example 
                // I just put the results into the TextView
                resultsTxt.setText(format + "\n" + contents);
                break;
            case ACTIVITY_1:
                // TODO: handle the return of the SecondActivity
                break;
            case ACTIVITY_2:
                // TODO: handle the return of the ThirdActivity
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
    {
        // Handle cancel. If the user presses 'back' 
        // before a code is scanned.
        resultsTxt.setText("Canceled");
    }
}
```

**Update**
For a bit more elegant result, you can create your own type of list item data:
**`CustomerListItem.java`**

```
public class CustomerListItem
{
    private String label;
    private Class<?> activity;

    /**
     * @param label
     * @param activity
     */
    public CustomerListItem(String label, Class<?> activity)
    {
        super();
        this.label = label;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    /**
     * @return the label
     */
    public String getLabel()
    {
        return label;
    }

    /**
     * @param label the label to set
     */
    public void setLabel(String label)
    {
        this.label = label;
    }

    /**
     * @return the activity
     */
    public Class<?> getActivity()
    {
        return activity;
    }

    /**
     * @param activity the activity to set
     */
    public void setActivity(Class<Activity> activity)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.label;
    }
}
```

Using this class you are able to bind an `Activity` to a list item, so when it will be clicked, you will know which `Activity` to start.

Your `Customer.java` class will look like:

```
public class Customer extends ListActivity
{
    TextView selection;
    CustomerListItem[] items = { 
            new CustomerListItem("Start Trip", StartTripActivity.class), 
            new CustomerListItem("Clock in", ClockinActivity.class), 
            new CustomerListItem("Customer Svc", CustomerSvcActivity.class), 
            new CustomerListItem("Independent Inspection", IInspectionActivity.class), 
            new CustomerListItem("Pick Up", PickUpActivity.class), 
            new CustomerListItem("Log Out", LogoutActivity.class)};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CustomerListItem>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
        selection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selection);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, items[position].getActivity());
        startActivityForResult(intent, position);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            // Perform different actions based on from which activity is
            // the application returning:
            switch (requestCode)
            {
                case 0:
                    // TODO: handle the return of the StartTripActivity
                    break;
                case 1:
                    // TODO: handle the return of the ClockinActivity
                    break;
                case 2:
                    // TODO: handle the return of the CustomerSvcActivity
                    // and so on...
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
            resultsTxt.setText("Canceled");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I would like to ask you as for activity 2 do you have a sample for time/date as the user click on "clock in" in the listview it will send the current/date to the database right away. As for activity 3 i would like to know sample how to put in the hardcode number for "log out" user wont be able to log out but their manager would have to approve and logout themselves.

Comment: I would love to help you out, though I suggest you to open a new thread for these questions, so to keep StakOverflow clean, with answers focusing on a specific issue. This way others might find helpful them. Thank you!

Comment: by the way the first 3 lines do I put that before or after textview selection string?

Comment: As I am playing around with the coding Im still confuse on how to connect which activity(intent) to which item of the list. For example, how can i link customer svc, independent inspection, and pick up items to the activity_0 (for barcode scanning) and ensure the data is sent under that specific item?

Comment: the first three lines are `private static final` members of your class, so no matter where they are declared in your code. By convention the `static final` members are the first to be declared, then the `final`, after them `static` variables, and the class members last. Then come your methods.

Comment: great i understand. Now I want to know how to link the activity to each of the item in the listview. Im having hard time trying to get them linked which is which.

Comment: I'd suggest creating your custom class `MyListItem {label:String, activity: class}`, and change your `items` variable from `String[]` to `MyListItem[]`. This way you'll know exactly for which label which activity is bound. Your `onListItemClick` method would be a lot easier too: `final MyListItem item = items[position]; startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, item.activity), position); You have to override the `MyListItem`'s `toString` to return the `label` member, then your adapter will work just fine without modifying it!

Comment: Im sorry I cant seem to pick up on that or understand it. Can you rephrase it again for more 'understandable' for me or a small sample code thanks =)

Comment: Sorry for not having enough time for thorough explanation, but hopefully the update code above will be clear enough to get you started :)